# Aligning an SVG element to the left hand side of page

Tags: html, css, svg

I've started tooling around with SVG and it is going good.

I am trying working the alignment of the image to the up corner of the left-hand side, however, I just could not make it well.  I want to show a quarter of the circle on the front page.

I've set something up by margin, right and top but the effect is not for what I want.  The SVG moves a little to the left-hand side of the page only still far away. (image below).

Guys- I am trying hard but if anyone could any resources or support then it would be highly appreciated.

The first image that I attached is what I made, but the second image is what I want to align.

Thank you

```css
.topcon {
  background-color: #f6f5f5;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height:250px;
  border: 15px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 150px auto 150px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  }

  .top-circle
  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 700px;
  top: 40px;
  margin: -200px auto -200px autp;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">



  <title>Frontend Mentor | Profile card component</title>

  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    body {
  background-color:  #00B6C7;
  width: 1440px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<img class="top-circle"src="images/bg-pattern-top.svg" alt="big circle on top">

<body>

  <div class="topcon">
  <h1>This is for what I made</h1>
  <h1>I want the circle could go up and only show quarter of the circle</h1>
  Victor Crest
  26
  London

  80K
  Followers

  803K
  Likes

  1.4K
  Photos
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFatu.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idf6L.jpg)

Comment: what does bg-pattern-top.svg contain?

Comment: I put the svg file into the following url in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sksmxcxwi4t8bsw/AAC5zJI8IoOxQ38DzG9RjmUTa?dl=0